# Why is "T *&root" being passed for insert operation in a binary tree?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I was creating a custom binary tree and has stumbled in the following code for correct insertion in the tree from this [site](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs225/s03/binary_trees/).

```
void treeInsert(TreeNode *&root, string newItem) {
    if ( root == NULL ) {
        root = new TreeNode( newItem );
        return;
    }
    else if ( newItem < root->item ) {
        treeInsert( root->left, newItem );
    }
    else {
        treeInsert( root->right, newItem );
    }
}
```

Why do you need to passed `TreeNode *&root` instead of `TreeNode *root`?

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a pointer, rather than a reference to a pointer, modifications that you do to that pointer itself would be local to your `treeInsert` function. This prevents you from inserting the root - the only case when you must modify the pointer itself (the third line in your source code).

For example, if you do this

```
TreeNode *root = NULL;
treeInsert(root, "hello");
```

and `treeInsert` takes `TreeNode*`, the value of `root` after the call of `treeInsert` will remain `NULL`, because the third line of your source code would modify a local copy of the `root` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case when your newItem is the root item. Then this will change your root element. This means that at the end of the operation, your note 'root' has to point to the newly inserted TreeNode.

Now if you only pass `TreeNode *root`, you can only change the value, but at the end, your root pointer cannot be changed. So, you have to pass your pointer by reference, so that you can change it within your function.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `TreeNode*` is passed by reference, so that the original pointer in the calling function can be changed, **in case the tree is empty.**

Otherwise, if you just pass a copy of the pointer, the modifications will be local to the function being called.

A comment is present in the code itself: *Note that root is passed by reference since its value can change in the case where the tree is empty.*

If you don't do this, you have a `NULL` pointer in the calling function representing the root of the tree, which is clearly wrong since you just inserted an element.

Some other ways of handling the situation are:

1. Returning the local `root` pointer

   `root = treeInsert(root, str);`
2. Passing pointer to root pointer, so it can be changed

   `treeInsert(&root, str);`